# SQL find the count of a table that has an attribute containing a string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `delayed_jobs` that has a column `last_error`. I want to get the count of rows that has the string "duplicate key" in the last_error attribute. So far I have gotten:

```
select count(1)
from delayed_jobs
```

Which returns:

`6880`

The number should be closer to 100.

Answer (score 2):

Found it! It should be:

```
select count(1)
from delayed_jobs
where last_error like '%duplicate key%'
```

Which returns `68`